# Why does changing the body's background color change the entire page's background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I logged the height and padding values using this code:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function() {

    console.log( jQuery('body').css('height') );
    console.log( jQuery('body').css('padding-top') );
    console.log( jQuery('body').css('padding-bottom'));

}); //end ready
```

This outputs:

```
20px
0px
0px
```

If the height of the body is only 20 pixels, why does the entire background of the browser change black when I use this CSS:

```
body {
    background: black;
}
```

I'm using Chrome as my browser.  If you're curious as to how I ran into this question, I ran into a problem of adding a click event to the body that didn't ever seem to fire due to the body's default height.

Comment: Body refers to the hole <body></body> tag. If I were you I would add a div inside your body and change the property of this div.

Comment: Does it happen even when you set `html{ background:blue; }` for example?

Comment: @Michał Yes, the whole page turns blue using `html{ background:blue; }`

Comment: And the 20px high `<body>` remains black?

Comment: @Michal Ah so the reason the height is 20px is because I left the word "Hello" in the body. Taking that out made the body have a height of 0px.  But yes, the 20px body remained black when I left the word "hello" in there, and the rest of the page was blue.

Comment: Check [this post](http://css-tricks.com/just-one-of-those-weird-things-about-css-background-on-body/)

Comment: @tliokos Great link. Between you and adeneo, I think I have my question answered.  Basically it's just something strange the developers did and there isn't much intuition behind it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A long time ago there was something called `document.bgcolor`, or something like that, that would let you set the background of the document itself, but that was deprecated.

Instead it was decided that setting `document.body.style.backgroundColor`, or in other words setting the background of the body, would also set the background color for the `document` automagically, as the `document` object has no `styl`e property, but it's still visible when the body/html elements does not completely cover the document, that's why the entire page goes black even if the body element does not cover the entire document.

Comment: Is this webkit-specific?

Comment: Okay I see it was in the W3 spec. I tried changing the DTD around and it still works automagically. That's neat. I guess it makes sense because a lot of people don't think about styling the html element.

Comment: I think this is the history lesson I was looking for.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @BumbleB2na - It's not the HTML element either, it's the document, something completely different.

Comment: Ohhhh, it totally makes sense now! If we set the background of the body, that sets the background of the document.  BUT if we set the background of the html element, that sets the background of the document.  However, the neither the body nor the html "box" take up the entire page (unless we modify the dimensions w CSS), they're smaller boxes that sit on top of the document which does take up the whole page.

Comment: @KacyRaye - Sounds about right, the document is what you see when no other elements are covering it, it's what contains everything else, but it can't really be styled as it's not really an element. So setting the background of the body sets the background of the document in some cases to fill the entire page with that color, makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

> The  element contains all the contents of an HTML document, such
>   as text, hyperlinks, images, tables, lists, etc.

Says the definition at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_body.asp). Having in mind this definition, if the `<html>` element doesn't the style of `<body>` is considered representation of the document's style. Our little investigation from the comments proves this.

**Edit:**

Didn't see the comment from the question. The [link](http://css-tricks.com/just-one-of-those-weird-things-about-css-background-on-body/) by [tliokos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1194545/tliokos) mentions the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a click event on a full-sized body, try this:

```css
body{
    background-color: black;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I was aware of this.  I'm more looking for an answer to why the body tag behaves the way it does.

Comment: The body element inherits its height from it's content. Most browser have a initial body height of 0px and an initial margin of 8px. the reason the body doesn't cover the whole page is in its name: body of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to understand what is the body, and bare in mind the body is everything you see when page loads so in order to divide your page add a div or table and change its background.

Comment: The body isn't everything you see when the page loads.
If you don't put anything in the body, the height is 0 pixels.
Everything you see when the page loads is the document and whatever you put on top of it.